# How to improve speed of DynamoDB requests

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I've been testing out DynamoDB as a potential option for a scalable and steady throughput database for a site that will be hit pretty frequently and requires a very fast response time (< 50ms). I'm seeing pretty slow responses (both locally and on an EC2 instance) for the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        AWSCredentials credentials = new PropertiesCredentials(new File("aws_credentials.properties"));
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials);
        System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " (ms) to connect");
        DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Model model = mapper.load(Model.class, "hashkey1", "rangekey1");
        System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - start) + " (ms) to load Model");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The connection to the DB alone takes about `800 (ms)` on average and the loading using the `mapper` takes an additional `200 (ms)`. According to [Amazon's page about DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/) we should expect "Average service-side latencies...typically single-digit milliseconds." I wouldn't expect the full round-trip HTTP request to add that much overhead. Are these expected numbers even on an EC2 instance?

Comment: I'm not a java programmer, but I would verify whether there is in fact any "connecting" going on until you call mapper.load... you might want to verify that with some network packet capture.  For my money, the delay is being spent instantiating the necessary objects, not with doing the actual work  Two or more consecutive requests, reusing other objects where possible might offer interesting benchmarks. DynamoDB only uses a REST Interface behind the scenes, afaik, so presumably, there's no "connection" to make until you send a quety.

Comment: Yea, I ran those kinds of tests and the consecutive numbers are the ones listed above. The initial numbers are worse, but not by a lot. I also actually took a look at the server side latency in DynamoDB console and saw times of about 40ms for a single read, which is pretty crazy high, at least for my use case.

Comment: What odds the size of the object you are trying to read?

Comment: It's tiny, it has the hash key, range key, and a version attribute.

Comment: Stupid question: are your EC2 instance and the Dynamo endpoint you're talking to in the same region (us-east-1, for example)?

Comment: Yup, both are in us-east-1.

Answer (score 4):

I think a better test would be to avoid the initial costs/latency incurred in starting up the JVM and loading the classes.  Something like:

```
public class TestDynamoDBMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            AWSCredentials credentials = new PropertiesCredentials(new File("aws_credentials.properties"));
            AmazonDynamoDBClient client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient(credentials);
            DynamoDBMapper mapper = new DynamoDBMapper(client);
            // Warm up
            for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
                testrun(mapper, false);
            }
            // Time it
            for (int i=0; i < 10; i++) {
                testrun(mapper, true);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }    
    }

    private static void testrun(DynamoDBMapper mapper, boolean timed) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        Model model = mapper.load(Model.class, "hashkey1", "rangekey1");
        if (timed)
            System.out.println(
                TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(System.nanoTime() - start)
                + " (ms) to load Model");
    }
}
```

Furthermore, you may consider enabling the default metrics of the AWS SDK for Java to see the fine grain time allocation in Amazon CloudWatch.  For more details, see:

[http://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx1O0S3I51OTZWT/Taste-of-JMX-Using-the-AWS-SDK-for-Java](http://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx3C0RV4NRRBKTG/Enabling-Metrics-with-the-AWS-SDK-for-Java)

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 Thanks, I appreciate the effort and code. I tried this out and saw the same numbers. As I mentioned in a comment above, I'm seeing 40ms server-side latency, which is already a bad start for my application. :) I'll try out the fine grain time allocation in CloudWatch.

Comment: Hi Marc, it sounds to me the 40ms includes not only server-side latency, but also the network latency between the client and server, as well as the client side processing time, or possibly even retries by the Jakarta commons httpclient used underneath.  In any case, I am curious what you see in CloudWatch when the default metrics is enabled.

Answer (score 3):

Dynamo DB is located in a specific region (they dont yet support cross region replication). This is chosen by you when you create a table. Unless you are calling the APIs from the same region, it is bound to be slow.

It looks like you are trying to call Dynamo from your development desktop. You can re-do the same test from an EC2 instance started in the "same region". This will considerably speed up the responses. This is a more realistic test, since any way when you deploy your production system it will be in the same region as Dynamo.

Again, if you really need very quick response, consider using ElastiCache between your code and Dynamo. On every read, store on cache before returning the results. Next read should read from the cache (say for an expiry time of 10 mins). For "read-heavy" apps this is the suggested route. I have seen many fold better response using this approach.